# Writing a Python compiler for practice

Tags: python, compiler-construction

Recently I've been reading quite a bit about CPUs and architectures; mainly opcodes, Integrated Circuits, etc.  I've been a python developer for a few years, and I'd like to get some practice in writing machinecode.

I thought for fun I'd compile a very simple python script into machinecode as a way to practice it.  The script is as follows:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = a + b
print c
```

I'm writing the compiler in python, because I'm not as good at C as I am at python.  I've looked a round a little, and I have the following python libraries at my disposal, which might help, i.e.

```
binascii.hexify(hex(2))  <-- should convert 2 to binary, correct?

file = open('/usr/local/bin/my_sample_program','wb') <-- should write the resulting binary file
```

I still have to find the opcodes for Intel Core i5, but that should be easy to.

My question is as follows:

1) How do I write the opcode to the file?  In other words, assume the opcode for setting a register to contain the value 2 is *0010* how do I write this is as the first four numbers in the program's first line of execution?

2) How do I tell the OS, either OS X or Ubuntu, to load the program into physical memory?  I'm assuming that the first thing a compiler does is write instructions for the OS onto the resulting binary file?

3) Any resources that you might know of that can help me would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code for the Python interpreter?

Comment: What you're trying to do is difficult.  To generate a platform-specific machine code executable, you need to familiarize yourself with the platform-specific formats.  Ubuntu, for example, uses the ELF format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf_format)

Comment: @CharlesSalvia I was under the impression that it's architecture dependent.  I.e. any machinecode for Intel i5 should work on any other i5 CPU on any other OS, the rest is just OS dependent?  Is that wrong?

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Read the wiki.  So I think it answers question number 2 in my questions.  Thanks, will dig more into ELF.

Answer (score 7):

That is quite a project you are planning there. In addition to learning how a compiler works, you also need to read up on loadable file formats like ELF, and tons of information on operating-system details.

I would suggest that you would emit an *assembly file* as output of your compiler. Then you could use an existing assembler to convert the file into machine code. In fact, this is what most C compilers (including GCC) do "under the surface".

**EDIT:** The output of a compiler or an assembler is typically an *object file*. This is later combined with other object files by a linker. Writing the entire tool chain, compiler, assembler, linker, and other associated tools would easily multiple man-years. In this light, I don't think that you should see a straight-forward solution like using an existing assembler and linker as cheating.

Comment: Interesting about the gcc compiler, I didn't know that.  Using an assembler would also make the out program less platform specific, no? So, theoretically I should be able to run my simple program under Ubuntu and OS X, I'd just have to make sure I'm using the right assembler at compile time...

Comment: I also think that using an assembler should be *Phase I*.  I'd still like to learn more, so I'll have to dig into ELF once I get the first phase right.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling python isn't easy. You could look at [pypy](http://pypy.org/) which has a just-in-time compiler.

Another option is to start with the python [bytecode](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-bytecode) that is saved in a `.pyc` file if a python program is run by the standard Cpython interpreter. 
This has a limited amount of instructions for which you'd have to generate assembly/executable code for your CPU.

Note that you would also have to write a *large* amount of code to implement all built-in types and functions!